# -bash: /usr/local/bin/heroku: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, bash, heroku

Whenever I open a new terminal window I now get:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/heroku: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Any idea as to why this is happening and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure the first line of the file `/usr/local/bin/heroku` is `#!/path/to/ruby`.  You may need to change it from `/usr/local/bin/ruby` to `/usr/bin/ruby`, or if you cannot find the `ruby` executable, type `which ruby` or `updatedb && locate ruby` to find it.

---

If the above doesn't work...

Check your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.inputrc~`, `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/inputrc`, `/etc/profile` for a line trying to execute `/usr/local/bin/heroku`.

Another idea is you might have this as one of your startup programs.  Check in `/etc/inittab` for a line with `/usr/local/bin/heroku`.

If you still cannot find that line in any of those files you can run `grep -iH heroku /*`

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install wget
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/heroku: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

You should firstly read the massage that the terminal throw out. `/usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` that means there is no valid `ruby` command in the `/usr/local/bin`. So if you have install `ruby` but in another directory. You can use `ln -s` to link the `/usr/local/bin/` directory. So find it out, such as `/usr/bin/ruby`. You can get into`/usr/local/bin/`directory run `ln -s /usr/bin/ruby`. If you have not started installing `ruby`, you should install it and make sure the `ruby` command in the `/usr/local/bin` directory

Comment: I downvoted because the OP has obviously already read the message and is asking here because they need help understanding what it means. "You should firstly read the massage that the terminal throw out" is just trying to make them feel bad, and is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install heroku? If from source, you should recompile with proper directories.

You can edit `/usr/local/bin/heroku` but I think better when you recompile it (who knows where are more bad settings in heroku).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which resulted in the following error message when I tried to run any heroku commands:

```
(~/).gem/ruby/1.8/bin/heroku: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

After some searching, I found a copy of the heroku-api gem in ~/.gem/ruby/1.8/cache. Deleting it and deleting the rubygems reference file in ~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was running "pod init" in a directory. This gave me a similar error:

```
 -bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Solution: install Cocoapods following the directions on their website.