# irb interpreter error: -bash: /usr/local/bin/irb: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/ruby/2.1.1_1/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, rvm, irb

I'm Mac OS X 10.9.4 user and have system ruby version 2.0.0. Started learning ruby i've decided to get new version. I've done it using `rvm get stable`. It works almost fine except interactive mode.

When i call `irb` in terminal, i receive:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/irb: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/ruby/2.1.1_1/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
```

`ruby -v` prompts `ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was quite easy. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907055/bash-usr-local-bin-heroku-usr-local-bin-ruby-bad-interpreter-no-such-file) was almost the same problem.

Solution:

Open `/usr/local/bin/irb` and configure ruby interpreter path. Mine was `@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/ruby/2.1.1_1/bin/ruby` and i only had to change `@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@` to `/usr/local/Cellar/`

I suppose that another possible solution would be defining `@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@` var, but i'm new to ruby and hence not sure.