# Can't install Rails on El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

**DISCLAIMER:** I am on a machine where numerous things have most probably been installed, uninstalled, moved around and/or somehow modified so I can't really provide a lot of information on what has happened before I got my hands on it. I would be more than grateful, however, to use this situation as an opportunity to better understand how all these tools work so please don't hesitate to answer even with steps I could probably follow to solve the problem I have.

Short Version:

`rbenv` is used for `ruby` and the current installed version is `2.3.0`

`brew -v` outputs `Homebrew 0.9.9 (no git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 8427; last commit 2016-08-01)`

The latest version of `Xcode` is installed and `gcc` outputs

`Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

Now, I (suppossedly) "install" rails

(`gem install rails` outputs `Successfully installed rails-5.0.0
1 gem installed`)

but straight after that `rails -v` outputs `-bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Is there maybe some way to do a clean uninstall and install of all the aforementioned tools?

Comment: try `which ruby` and then symlink that to where rails is looking (`/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`)

Comment: or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907055/bash-usr-local-bin-heroku-usr-local-bin-ruby-bad-interpreter-no-such-file

Comment: Try following [this blog](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html), it helped me to setup rails after so many failures. Just skip the steps if you have already done it.

Comment: You can get rails installed to this location like this: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin/ rails `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your suggestions to look in those other questions and after some more digging, I ended up limiting the error to `Not a directory` which led me to an `rbenv` [issue](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/886) that pointed me to the possibility of *having `/usr/local/bin` at the head of my PATH after initializing rbenv*. And, as jeremy writes, *that's why invoking rails is finding the executable in `/usr/local/bin/` instead of in `/Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/shims/`*. So I removed that line and problem solved!